# How to mimic Instagram/TikTok HLS streaming capabilities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm converting a .mp4 file to HLS in Node.js and storing it in S3. What are the important options to pass in here? I'm currently passing in the below, because that's what was suggested in some online tutorial I followed.

```
'-profile:v baseline',
'-level 3.0',
'-start_number 0',
'-hls_time 3',
'-hls_list_size 0',
'-f hls'
```

Should I be lowering the hls_time parameter to say, 1? Isn't the smaller that number, the more granular each segment is, and the quicker each segment of the stream will be loaded on the client side? What are other things to consider here? I'd like to get as close to TikTok/Instagram media playing capabilities as possible.

Comment: Smaller segments may cause more network stalls due to overhead.  Apple [recommends 6 seconds per segment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices), though you should test under your target conditions to see what'll work best for your scenarios.